# Conditional formatting in Excel 2010 with variable inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find a conditional formatting rule in Excel that will highlight a cell if the header of its field is found in a different cell in that row. I have a data set with several fields including one called 'Failures' which lists the fields in each record that contain values outside of certain parameters. The data is from an outside source, so I do not have the parameters to make individual rules for each field.  I want to highlight the cells in each record listed in it's 'Failures' cell.  Is there a way to do this?

**This is what the data looks like now:**

[image: This is what the data looks like now]

**This is what I want it to look like:**

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Comment: ... "different cell in that row" ... So, your data is written horizontally with headers in the `A` column?

Comment: No. The headers are at the top as usual, but there is a field that references the headers.

Comment: Updated answer.  Thanks for the example. Helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formating > New rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format >

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$1,$E2))
```

Applies to `=$A$2:$D$9`

Comment: Sure, try it.  The header in row `1` just needs to be found in column `E`.